# Solving the ODE $(x^2 y-1)y'-(xy^2-1)=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve $(x^2 y-1)y'-(x y^2-1)=0$.

Not sure how to approach this ODE, would love some help regarding solving it or any useful resources.

Comment: This ODE was quite challenging for me to solve. Out of curiosity, where does this problem come from?

Comment: @projectilemotion I’ll credit my college professor , this is from last years ODE’s course Exam .

Comment: That is helpful to know. If this problem is exactly as you have written, that is an unusually difficult problem for an exam (even Wolfram Alpha cannot solve it). However, if what was really meant was $$(x^2 y-1)y'\color{red}{+}(xy^2-1)=0,$$ then the problem is not difficult (this is an exact equation, so one can follow the method in https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/exact.aspx).

Comment: @projectilemotion my question has $-$ and I do agree it’s a challenging ODE , moreover it had only 15% of the total grade , Meaning 25 min to solve it

Comment: In that case, I suspect one of three things: 1) It's a typo (which was possibly mentioned by the professor during the exam). 2) Your professor made a mistake when trying to construct an exact equation (or one which can be made exact using a simple integrating factor $x^m y^n$ or an integrating factor only in terms of one variable). 3) Your professor is sadistic :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Substitute $y(x)=xv(x)$. Then $y'(x)=v(x)+xv'(x)$ and hence we obtain the ODE
$$v'(x)=\frac{v(x)-1}{x^4 v(x)-x}$$
An obvious solution to this differential equation is $v(x)=1$, i.e. $y(x)=x$. To find other solutions, note that the form of the ODE suggests that we write $v'(x)=\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{1}{dx/dv}=\frac{1}{x'(v)}$ and treat $v$ as the independent variable. This gives a [Bernoulli ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation)
$$x'(v)+\frac{1}{v-1}x(v)=\frac{v}{v-1}(x(v))^4.$$
The canonical substitution $u(v)=\frac{1}{x(v)^3}$ reduces this to the linear ODE
$$\frac{du}{dv}-\frac{3}{v-1}u(v)=-\frac{3v}{v-1}.$$
Solving this using your favorite method (e.g. integrating factors) gives
$$u(v)=\frac{1}{2}(3v-1)+C(v-1)^3$$
for some arbitrary constant $C$. Plugging everything back in and simplifying gives the general solution (in implicit form)
$$\frac{3}{2}yx^2-\frac{x^3}{2}+C(y-x)^3=1. \tag{$\ast$}$$

Note that in theory you could make these solutions explicit by solving some cubic equation, but they do not have simple expressions.

For visualisation, one can plot these solutions using e.g. [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ek3mghlvd3). Note that I have verified that these solutions coincide with Mathematica's numerical solutions.

**Remark:** In a certain sense the trivial solution $y(x)=x$ is a limiting case ($C\to \infty$) of the general solution found in $(*)$. One can see this intuitively by setting $C$ to be very large in the Desmos plot.

Comment: You inspired me ! Thanks and (+1)

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment*

Using @projectilemotion's answer, we can easily solve the cubic equation
$$y^3-3x y^2+\frac{3 (2 C+1) x^2}{2 C}y-\frac {(2 C+1) x^3+2 }{2C}=0$$

For $C=1$, the solution is
$$y=x \left(1-\sqrt{2} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\frac{
   \left(x^3-1\right)}{x^3}\right)\right)\right)$$

For $C=2$,
$$y=x \left(1-\sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(2-\frac{2}{x^3}\right)\right)\right)$$

So, trying the substitution $y=x \left(1-e^{z}\right)$, the differential equation becomes
$$\left(x^4 \left(e^{z}-1\right)+x\right) z'+1=0$$ Switch variables
$$\frac{\left(e^z-1\right) x^4+x}{x'}+1=0$$ Let $x=\frac 1{\sqrt[3]t}$
$$t'-3 t-3 e^z+3=0\quad \implies t=c_1 \,e^{3 z}+\frac{1}{2} \left(2-3 e^z\right)$$

Now, back to $x$ and $y$ for the implicit solution.

Comment: (+1) The solutions for these special values of $C$ are actually much nicer than I expected! The case $C=1$ corresponds to e.g. the initial condition $y(0)=1$ (which is studied quite often).